# IoT Analytics Device Registration

Tags: intel, iot, intel-edison

I'm trying to register my Edison, then I typed the following command with activation code. But, IoT Analytics said Device already exists even though I haven't registered any device. Does anyone have an idea to fix this?

Thanks

```
root@itpsandbox:~# iotkit-admin activate 'activation code'
2016-10-19T02:42:31.851Z - info: Activating ...
2016-10-19T02:42:32.872Z - error: Activation Rejected:{"code":1409,"message":"Device already exists"}  --> error
2016-10-19T02:42:32.882Z - error: Error in the activation process ... 300
```

Comment: If iotkit-admin is an intel supplied tool, I suggest you cross post to software.intel.com. Intel's site is a mess (nothing new there). I think they've merged the IoT Forum with the Maker Forum. I'll also forward your question to some people I know.

Comment: Taylor Kidd, thank you so much.